# msi with C#-webview2 does not work with webview

Tags: c#, deployment, windows-installer, publish, webview2

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
             Load += Form1_Load;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.webView21.Source = new Uri("https://www.google.com");
        }
    }
}
```

I am a student just starting to learn C#.
If you simply write the code as above and publish it with (Clickonce) publish,
the webview will work normally.
However, if you make it as an msi file, the webview does not work.
Can you help me with what needs to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common cause is the `WebView2Loader.dll` not being included.

Sometimes it needs to be manually included.

See [Distribute your app and the WebView2 Runtime - Files to ship with the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution#files-to-ship-with-the-app)

Also see these discussions of the issue...

[Deployed C# app using WebView2 cannot find the Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/456717/deployed-c-app-using-webview2-cannot-find-the-runt)

[WebView2Loader.dll is left out when publishing](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/1061)

[WebView2Loader.dll is missing from the Installer Folder](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/1121)

[WebView2 works in debug but not when published with ClickOnce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71265161/webview2-works-in-debug-but-not-when-published-with-clickonce)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have learned a lot from you.

The problem has been solved, but a new problem has arisen. It seems that WebView2 cannot operate because it does not have permission to create a new folder in the program files folder. However, I do not have the ability to solve this problem. Is there an easier way to solve this?

Comment: Is it failing when trying to create the user data folder (UDF)? They say in most cases you should [specify a custom UDF location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/user-data-folder?tabs=dotnet#tabpanel_2_dotnet).

Comment: Is the UDF you mentioned referring to C:\USER

Comment: If you don't supply a custom location then it will default to the Program Files folder, which you don't want. The recommended location appears to be the user's application data folder which you can get programmatically with `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867485/c-sharp-getting-the-path-of-appdata)

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
The above explanation seems a little complicated to me, so I set the default installation folder to the c:\myapp folder and installed it, and the program works. Are there any differences between doing what you described and the way I do it?

Comment: Your way, the UDF location will always be c:\myapp. You just need to consider if different users will log on & use your app on the same machine, then they may be able to see another user's data. If you create the file using the code in my previous comment then each user will get their own UDF created in their own folders e.g. C:\Users\davmos\AppData\Roaming

Comment: thanks a lot.  I have learned a lot from you.